# substract integer value from datetime field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I want to subtract an integer value from a `datetime` field. Here `date_joined` is a `datetime` field and age is an integer field.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):  
    profiles = profiles.objects.all()
    for profile in profiles: 
        age = person.age
        date_joined = person.date_joined
        date_of_birth = date_joined - age
        p = date_of_birth(date_of_birth = date_of_birth,activated = 1)
        p.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class profiles(models.Model):
    date_joined =  models.DateTimeField (max_length=1)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
date_joined - (datetime.timedelta(365) * age)
```

To subtract `age` years from `date_joined`.

Just a note that this is a good quick-and-dirty solution, but is not very robust. Consider the following output:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 12) - datetime.timedelta(365) * 15
datetime.datetime(1998, 12, 16, 0, 0)
```

As you can see, because of leap years (years that actually have 366 days), the result is 4 days after the date we actually wanted. A more robust solution would be:

```
date_joined.replace(year = date_joined.year - age)
```